# Как запустить Activity без добавления в back stack?

Tags: android, activity, backstack

Имеется Activity, которая запускается при старте приложения

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.InitActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

После необходимой инициализации из нее запускается другая MainActivity (основная). При нажатии на кнопку "Back", InitActivity возвращается из back stack, хотя этого происходить не должно. Как реализовать подобный функционал?

Поиск не дал ответ для моей ситуации. Прописывание в манифесте параметра `android:noHistory="true"` не подходит, т.к. в InitActivity происходит запрос на получении геопозиции и в случае, если GPS модуль отключен вызывается диалговое окно для включения, после его закрытия InitActivity уже нет в back stack из-за этого параметра и происходит просто выход из приложения.

Comment: Попробуйте перед стартом главной активити финишировать сплэш активити

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В манифесте укажи что MainActivity запускается со следующими параметрами:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

**clearTaskOnLaunch="true"** - чтобы таск очищался после запуска MainActivity, 
**launchMode="singleTop"** - чтобы MainActivity в таске всегда была только в одном экземпляре

Comment: Спасибо, вопрос решён.

Answer (score 0):

Почему этого происходить не должно? это в порядке вещей. А вообще просто после запуска MainActivity завершайте InitActivity -     InitActivity.this.finish();

Comment: этого не должно происходить для моей ситуации, после запуска MainActivity вызываю `finish()` но это, на удивление, не помогает, при нажатии "Back" всё равно возвращаюсь в InitActivity